# Do thread that are converted to fibers leak when they are not converted back to threads

Tags: c++, windows, winapi

I am creating a fiber class, and it would be much easier to use if the user didn't have to manually call `ConvertThreadToFiber` for every thread that wants to use it. So I would prefer to call this function whenever the class is used and check for `ERROR_ALREADY_FIBER` instead.

If I do this, is the fiber part of the thread cleaned up automatically when the thread exits, or is calling `ConvertFiberToThread` a requirement to not leak anything?

Comment: Wow, people still use fibers? I thought that was a dead technology.

Comment: yes, will be leak. `NT_TIB ::FiberData` heap block will be leak

Comment: @rem [Fibers aren’t useful for much any more; there’s just one corner of it that remains useful for a reason unrelated to fibers](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/oldnewthing/20191011-00/?p=102989).